# How can I use @unchecked annotation in map

Tags: scala

I have a scenario where I have a list of objects of a certain trait. And I know for certain that the list will not contain certain implementations of the trait:

```
sealed trait T
case class A(i: Int) extends T
case class B(str: String) extends T
case class C() extends T

val list: List[T] = List(A(1), B("x"), A(2))

val strs = list.map {
    case A(i) => i.toString
    case B(str) => str
}
```

I wish to suppress the "match may not be exhaustive" warning for the call to map.
What is the syntax for using the @unchecked annotation here?

Comment: Why not using `collect` instead?

Comment: Its just a hypothetical example to show the syntax I need

Comment: I think the point still holds, why marking as `unchecked` a `map` instead of using `collect` which expects a **PartialFunction**, also `collect` won't fail in runtime if your suppositions are wrong.

Comment: Yep sorry you are right! I should have used collect